# Running 3 slideshows on the same page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to run 3 slideshows on one page. I tried the following the code, But when I click the buttons on the 3rd slideshow, It changes the images on the 2nd slideshow. Please help me to solve this issue

```js
var slideIndex = [1, 1, 1];
var slideId = ["mySlides1", "mySlides2", "mySlides3"]
showDivs(1, 0);
showDivs(1, 1);
showDivs(1, 2);

function plusDivs(n, no) {
  showDivs(slideIndex[no] += n, no);
}

function showDivs(n, no) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName(slideId[no]);
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex[no] = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex[no] = x.length}
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  x[slideIndex[no]-1].style.display = "block";  
}
```

```css
.mySlides {display:none;}
```

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<body>

<div class="w3-content w3-display-container">
  <img class="mySlides1" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_snowtops.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides1" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides1" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_mountains.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides1" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_forest.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-left" onclick="plusDivs(-1, 0)">&#10094;</button>
  <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-right" onclick="plusDivs(1, 0)">&#10095;</button>
</div>
<br>
<div class="w3-content w3-display-container">
  <img class="mySlides2" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_la.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides2" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_ny.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides2" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_chicago.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-left" onclick="plusDivs(-1, 1)">&#10094;</button>
  <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-right" onclick="plusDivs(1, 1)">&#10095;</button>
</div>
<br>
<div class="w3-content w3-display-container">
  <img class="mySlides3" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_la.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides3" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_ny.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides3" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_chicago.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-left" onclick="plusDivs(-1, 1)">&#10094;</button>
  <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-right" onclick="plusDivs(1, 1)">&#10095;</button>
</div>
```

Comment: You didn't update the `no` attribute that you're passing to the `plusDivs` function on your third slideshow. Your slideshow controls are set to control slideshows `0, 1, 1` instead of `0, 1, 2`.

Comment: @JonUleis please post an answer

Comment: No need, your problem was a simple typographical error and a comment sufficed.

Comment: @AmongUS You have 7 places in your code that have `plusDivs(...)` in it. The first one is the function itself. The other 6 are function calls. Look at all 6 function calls carefully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var slideIndex = [1, 1, 1];
var slideId = ["mySlides1", "mySlides2", "mySlides3"]
showDivs(1, 0);
showDivs(1, 1);
showDivs(1, 2);

function plusDivs(n, no) {
  showDivs(slideIndex[no] += n, no);
}

function showDivs(n, no) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName(slideId[no]);
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex[no] = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex[no] = x.length}
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  x[slideIndex[no]-1].style.display = "block";  
}
```

```css
.mySlides {display:none;}
```

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<body>

<div class="w3-content w3-display-container">
  <img class="mySlides1" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_snowtops.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides1" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides1" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_mountains.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides1" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_forest.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-left" onclick="plusDivs(-1, 0)">&#10094;</button>
  <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-right" onclick="plusDivs(1, 0)">&#10095;</button>
</div>
<br>
<div class="w3-content w3-display-container">
  <img class="mySlides2" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_la.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides2" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_ny.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides2" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_chicago.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-left" onclick="plusDivs(-1, 1)">&#10094;</button>
  <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-right" onclick="plusDivs(1, 1)">&#10095;</button>
</div>
<br>
<div class="w3-content w3-display-container">
  <img class="mySlides3" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_la.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides3" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_ny.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides3" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_chicago.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-left" onclick="plusDivs(-1, 2)">&#10094;</button>
  <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-right" onclick="plusDivs(1, 2)">&#10095;</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

in plusDivs second parameter is index of slider , in third slider you are selecting second slider thats why second slider is changing see image below
[image: ss]